# Prove or disprove an estimate involving the logarithm function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

I would to like know if the following estimate is true

$$ \ln(t+1)\ln\left(\frac{s}{t}+1\right)\geq \ln (2)\ln(s+1),\qquad \text{for all $0\leq s\leq t$}.$$

This is true at least for $t=s.$

If this fails, can we find a constant $c>0$ such that

$$ \ln(t+1)\ln\left(\frac{s}{t}+1\right)\geq c\ln(s+1),\qquad \text{for all $0\leq s\leq t$}.$$

Comment: Fix $t>0$ and use a computer to write down the graph of $s\mapsto \ln(t+1)\ln(s/t+1)-\ln(2)\ln(s+1)$ and see what happen... (-1 for a question that you could have easily solve alone).

Comment: Is this question so obvious that it deserves a downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote because it's an obvious question, I downvoted because it's not a good question. In particular, it would have been much quicker to draw the graph of your function on a computer to see that your inequality doesn't hold instead of asking if this inequality holds or not on MathStack. Moreover, it would also have answered your second question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, our inequality is not correct.

For $s=3~, t=5$ we get

$$\begin{align}0.84<&\ln 6\ln\left(\frac{3}{5}+1\right)
<0.96<\ln2\ln4&\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\ln 6\ln\left(\frac{3}{5}+1\right)<\ln2\ln4.\end{align}$$